# Unity keeps crashing due to unknown infinite loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop

So I am very nooby with C#. I am currently following a tutorial to make a memory game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prfzIpNhQMM).

I have followed it all and managed to fix all problems I ran into until now; every time I click play, Unity freezes. There a few comments on the videos of people having the same issues with the creator saying that its probably due to an infinite loop in the code. I do not have enough knowledge to enable me to recognise what one of those would be.

I know that the issue is with my GameManager script. If someone could take a look over it and see if they can find my issue, I would be most grateful:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite[] cardFace;
public Sprite cardBack;
public GameObject[] cards;
public Text matchText;

private bool _init = false;
private int _matches = 6;  


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!_init)
        initializeCards ();
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        checkCards();
}

void initializeCards()
{
    for(int id = 0; id < 2; id++)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            bool test = false;
            int choice = 0;
            while (!test) {
                choice = Random.Range(0, cards.Length);
                test = !(cards[choice].GetComponent<Card>().initialized);
            }
            cards[choice].GetComponent<Card>().cardValue = i;
            cards[choice].GetComponent<Card>().initialized = true;
        }
    }

    foreach (GameObject c in cards)
        c.GetComponent<Card>().setupGraphics();

    if (!_init)
        _init = true;

    }

public Sprite getCardBack()
{
    return cardBack;
}

public Sprite getCardFace(int i)
{
    return cardFace[i - 1];
}

void checkCards()
{
    List<int> c = new List<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < cards.Length; i++)
    {
        if (cards[i].GetComponent<Card>().state == 1)
            c.Add(i);
    }


    if (c.Count == 2)
        cardComparison(c);



}

void cardComparison(List<int> c)
{
    Card.DO_NOT = true;
    int x = 0;
    if(cards[c[0]].GetComponent<Card>().cardValue == cards[c[1]].GetComponent<Card> ().cardValue)
    {
        x = 2;
        _matches--;
        matchText.text = "Number of Matches: " + _matches;
        if (_matches == 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("VirusInfo3");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
    {

        cards[c[i]].GetComponent<Card>().state = x;
        cards[c[i]].GetComponent<Card>().falseCheck();
    }
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause infinite loop in this code. You have to post other scripts. It's likely not from this one you posted. I may be wrong...

Comment: I think you've made mistake _"I know that the issue is with my GameManager script"_ and you've posted the `Card` class.

Comment: Can you share your GameManager script?  There's one from the comments under the video: https://pastebin.com/MMV5gkFs, but I am not sure it's the same you have. If this is the case then checkCards() method has an infinite loop: ` for (int i = 0; 1 < cards.Length; i++)` as 1<cards.Length will always return true

Comment: Wow, I am a massive idiot, no idea how I managed to mix them up. Have edited the original question with the actual code now. Yeah @buxter I saw that comment and checked my own but it seems to be ok. Its defo the GameManager script as when I remove it, Unity works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only code part where I think something could lead to an infinite loop in your code is the following:

```
while (!test) {
    choice = Random.Range(0, cards.Length);
    test = !(cards[choice].GetComponent<Card>().initialized);
}
```

The problem of this section is that, if all your cards are initialized (so initialized being equal to true), your test variable will always be equal to false. So you will end up with while(!test) being while(true) everytime, leading to the infinite loop.

Add a way to not enter this while section or to exit it if such a case happens, and you should be done.

Comment: I worked it out. It was because I had put a 6 instead of a 7 in the part that it assigns a value. It works now! Thanks for your help

Comment: @AdamBeaumont Just so you know, this configuration looks really sketchy from an organization point and prone to failure (as evidenced by your question and the fix). If you want a random selection of cards, there's WAY better ways to do it. Like...creating an array, shuffling it, and popping the top N elements.

Comment: @Drac018s Yeah I thought there might be, however I am limited by time and programming ability. As long as it gets me a pass! Thanks for your suggestion